# How to merge an object with other object inner values in JavaScript without going through a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If my `state` object is like this,

```
this.state={
  input:{
    employee_count_range: {
        value: props.employee_count_range || '',
        errMsg: null
    },
    phone: {
        value: '',
        errMsg: null
    },
    city: {
        value: '',
        errMsg: null
    }
  }
}
```

and `user` object is like this,

```
let user = {
   employee_count_range: '',
   phone: '',
   city: ''
}
```

Is there any way of doing this with ES6 without going through a loop?

```
Object.keys(this.state.inputs)
     .map(field => user[field] = this.state.input[field].value);
```

I want to assign `state` object each inside `value` to `user` object values

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: Without going into a loop means - no loop at all (no map forEach, etc...) or no for/while loops?

Comment: @NarendraJadhav I want to assign `state` object inner values to `user` object.

Comment: @OriDrori yes no loop

Comment: @Lasitha - My question contained two options. Which is them is right ?

Comment: @OriDrori no maps, foreach, for/while loops

Comment: @Lasitha in user object already have `employee_count_range`,`phone` and also you have define wrong object `state` you have taken 2 `phone` keys in same object

Comment: my mistake @NarendraJadhav corrected

Comment: @Lasitha - Is it important that you discover the names of the properties in `this.state.inputs` dynamically, or is it okay to list them literally?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's ok to list them literally. I know I can do it with a loop. I just want to know if there's any possibility.

Answer (score 3):

In your reply to my question *"Is it important that you discover the names of the properties in this.state.inputs dynamically, or is it okay to list them literally?"*, [you've said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515885/how-to-merge-an-object-with-other-object-inner-values-in-javascript-without-goin#comment90001062_51515885):

> it's ok to list them literally. I know I can do it with a loop. I just want to know if there's any possibility.

Absolutely, no need for a loop at all, direct assignment is the simple, direct approach:

```
user.employee_count_range = this.state.inputs.employee_count_range.value;
user.phone = this.state.inputs.phone.value;
user.city = this.state.inputs.city.value;
```

Live example (using `state` rather than `this.state`):

```js
const state = {
  inputs: {
    employee_count_range: {
      value: 42
    },
    phone: {
      value: "123 456 7890"
    },
    city: {
      value: "London"
    }
  }
};
const user = {};

user.employee_count_range = state.inputs.employee_count_range.value;
user.phone = state.inputs.phone.value;
user.city = state.inputs.city.value;

console.log(user);
```

You can also use destructuring assignment to do it, but it doesn't buy you much of anything and it can be tricky to read:

```
({
  employee_count_range: {value: user.employee_count_range},
  phone: {value: user.phone},
  city: {value: user.city}
} = this.state.inputs);
```

Live example (using `state` rather than `this.state`):

```js
const state = {
  inputs: {
    employee_count_range: {
      value: 42
    },
    phone: {
      value: "123 456 7890"
    },
    city: {
      value: "London"
    }
  }
};
const user = {};

({
  employee_count_range: {value: user.employee_count_range},
  phone: {value: user.phone},
  city: {value: user.city}
} = state.inputs);

console.log(user);
```

---

**All of the below assumes you want to find the property names dynamically**, which it now turns out isn't the case.

If you mean you want to replicate this:

```
Object.keys(this.state.inputs)
     .map(field => user[field] = this.state.inputs[field].value);
```

...without any form of looping construct at all, then no, there's no way to do that. You'll need *some* kind of loop.

---

`map` isn't the right choice, though, because you're not using its return value. `forEach` or a `for-of` loop would be more appropriate choices:

```
Object.keys(this.state.inputs)
    .forEach(field => user[field] = this.state.inputs[field].value);
```

or

```
for (const field of Object.keys(this.state.inputs)) {
    user[field] = this.state.inputs[field].value;
}
```

You can avoid the second lookup (`this.state.iputs[field].value`) using `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys` (but it involves a bunch of temporary arrays, so...tradeoffs):

```
for (const [field, value] of Object.entries(this.state.inputs)) {
    user[field] = value;
}
```

or with `forEach`:

```
Object.entries(this.state.inputs).forEach(([field, value]) => {
    user[field] = value;
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort on this question.

Comment: @Lasitha - No worries. I've just updated the answer in light of your reply to my comment on the question. :-)